# Problema al implementar inversión de dependencias en Angular 10

Tags: angular

Estoy construyendo un servicio en angular 10 que sirve para recuperar y grabar el usuario activo en el Storage del navegador Web. Quiero dejarlo abierto para que pueda adaptarse a futuras implementaciones.

Para ello he hecho lo siguiente:

- He creado una interfaz que define las operaciones que tienen que realizar todas las implementaciones.
- El servicio implementa a la interfaz y está definido como @Injectable.
- En el componente en el que quiero utilizar mi servicio hago lo siguiente:

  - Inyecto el servicio en el constructor, como public, con tipo de la interfaz.
  - Utilizo el servicio como lo haría con cualquier otro servicio.

De esta forma me sale el siguiente error: "Can't resolve all parameters for HeaderComponent in .."

No sé si es que estoy haciendo algo mal o es que Angular tiene algunas limitaciones a la hora de utilizar la Inversión de Dependencias.

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?

Adjunto cómo tengo definidos los componentes:

- Interface: UsuarioConectadoI

```
/* Modelo que representa al usuario conectado */
import { UsuarioConectado } from '../models/usuario-conectado';

export interface UsuarioConectadoI {
    usuConectado: UsuarioConectado;

    /* Guarda el usuario conectado y lo asigna a usuConectado */
    grabarUsuarioConectado(usuario: UsuarioConectado);
    /* Elimina el usuario conectado y asigna null a usuConectado */
    borrarUsuarioConectado();
}
```

- Modelo: UsuarioConectado

```
export enum TipoUsuario{
    /* Tipo de usuario conectado */
    anonimo,
    admin,
    tutor,
    estudiante
 }
 
 export interface UsuarioConectado {
     username: string;
     token: string;
     tipo: TipoUsuario;
 }
```

- Servicio que implementa la interfaz: UsuarioConectadoStorageService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/* Clase abstracta que implementa a la interfaz */
import { TipoUsuario, UsuarioConectado } from '../models/usuario-conectado';
import { UsuarioConectadoI } from '../interfaces/usuario-conectado-i';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsuarioConectadoStorageService 
       implements UsuarioConectadoI{
  usuConectado: UsuarioConectado;

  grabarUsuarioConectado(usuario: UsuarioConectado) {
     //TODO: Realizar la implementación concreta
     this.usuConectado = {
       username: 'anubedam',
       token: 'fakeToken',
       tipo: TipoUsuario.anonimo
     }
  }
  borrarUsuarioConectado() {
    //TODO: Realizar la implementación concreta
    this.usuConectado = null;
  } 
}
```

- El componente cabecera consume el servicio. Es el que da el error.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

/* Servicio para recuperar el usuario conectado */
import { UsuarioConectadoI } from '../../interfaces/usuario-conectado-i';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit { 
  
  constructor(public conectadoService: UsuarioConectadoI) {
    /* Inyectamos la dependencia del servicio */ 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
(component) AppModule.HeaderComponent: class
class HeaderComponent
Can't resolve all parameters for HeaderComponent in c:/Users/Propietario/Desktop/Estudio/EstudioApp/src/app/shared/header/header.component.ts: (?).ng
```

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Agrega el código del servicio, del componente y cómo llamas al componente.

Comment: Modifico la descripción del problema para añadir la implementación. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón por la que no puede usar interfaces es porque una interfaz es un artefacto en tiempo de diseño de TypeScript. JavaScript no tiene interfaces. La interfaz TypeScript desaparece del JavaScript generado. No queda información de tipo de interfaz para que Angular la encuentre en tiempo de ejecución. Pero se puede usar una cadena como llave.

Agrega el servicio en el app.module de esta forma:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: "UsuarioConectadoI",
      useClass: UsuarioConectadoStorageService
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Y en el constructor del componente se recibe así:

```
constructor(
    @Inject("UsuarioConectadoI") public conectadoService: UsuarioConectadoI
  ) {
    conectadoService.borrarUsuarioConectado;
  }
```

[Demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nrwpzh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón del mundo. Debería haberme dado cuenta. Muchísimas gracias por ayudarme a encontrar solución a este problema.